# JOIN query not behaving as expected

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on a query that doesn't behave as expected, and would appreciate any help on pointing me in the right direction.

**TABLES**
I have three central tables consists of the following.

```
table_categories
- id (int)
- name (varchar)

table_events
- id (int)
- name (varchar)
- created (date time)

table_taxonomy
- cat_id (id from table_categories)
- event_id (id from table_events)
- type (varchar in this example always 'category')
```

**GOAL**
Count events created after a certain date in each category. The result should be something like:

```
COUNT   NAME    ID
3       Rock     1
2       Punk     3
```

**QUERY**
This is the query that I've come up with. The problem is that the result doesn't care about the created date, and grabs all events regardles of when they where created.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count,
            table_categories.name,
            table_categories.id
            FROM table_taxonomy
            INNER JOIN table_categories
            ON table_categories.id = table_taxonomy.cat_id
            LEFT JOIN table_events
            ON table_events.id = table_taxonomy.events_id
            WHERE table_taxonomy.type = 'category'
            AND table_taxonomy.cat_id IN(2,3)
            AND table_events.created > '2012-10-07 05:30:00'
            GROUP BY (table_categories.name)
```

Comment: what results are you getting from the query? please provide sample records.

Comment: You are `LEFT JOIN`ing table_events, but the `WHERE` condition drops all rows the `LEFT JOIN` would have included but `INNER JOIN` would not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this one, just small change while comparing date :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count,
            table_categories.name,
            table_categories.id
            FROM table_taxonomy
            INNER JOIN table_categories
            ON table_categories.id = table_taxonomy.cat_id
            LEFT JOIN table_events
            ON table_events.id = table_taxonomy.events_id
            WHERE table_taxonomy.type = 'category'
            AND table_taxonomy.cat_id IN(2,3)
            AND Date(table_events.created) > '2012-10-07 05:30:00'
            GROUP BY (table_categories.name)
```

Comment: my pleasure to help.. you can accept the answer as a correct, so other can easily resolve their same problem.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one,

```
SELECT  c.ID, c.Name, COUNT(*)
FROM    table_categories a
        INNER JOIN table_taxonomy b
            ON a.id = b.cat_id
        INNER JOIN table_events c
            ON b.event_ID = c.ID
WHERE   c.created > 'dateHere' 
        -- AND .....                  -- other conditions here
GROUP BY    c.ID, c.Name
```

Comment: Can you point to the difference between the asker's code and your code?

Comment: @JanDvorak the OP uses `LEFT JOIN` which is different from `INNER JOIN`